# How do I convert a font object into a mesh object using Python? -- Blender 3.4.1

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, font

I have been trying to use the bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH') to convert my font objects into mesh and curve objects.  I have observed other people reporting problems doing this conversion.  In the enclosed figure, the specific error that is reported is reported starting on line 22.  When I do this operation manually, the conversion works fine.  it is only when I try to write the python code that this problem happens.  Any suggestions would be much appreciated.  Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that `select_all` only sets the `Font Object` object as, well, `select`'d, not `active`. The `bpy.ops.object.convert` operator seems to expect that it is both `active` and `select`'d. (Also, side note; I avoid using `select_all` below, so that I don't select extra objects unintentionally.)

Making sure it is also the `active` object seems to work (tested in 2.83; I live in the past!):

```
import bpy
font_curve = bpy.data.curves.new(type="FONT", name="Font curve")
font_curve.body = "testing"
font_obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name="Font Object", object_data=font_curve)
bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(font_obj)
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = bpy.data.objects['Font Object'] # Need a reference to an `object`, not `TextCurve`, for this to work
bpy.context.object.select_set(True)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
```

Comment: Thank you NeverConvex for your insight in solving my problem.  I have tested for Blender 3.4.1 with both MESH and CURVE options for convert and works great! Best Regards!

Comment: Glad it helped -- since it seems to have fixed the problem, would be helpful if you marked the answer as `Accepted`